# How should I use sharepoint for facility booking?

Tags: development, calendar

Our company use sharepoint 2010, we would like to use sharepoint for facility booking, following are some basic requirements:
1.Users can submit application form( including who submit, where they book, time, remarks)
2.User can see a calendar page by different facilities, where they can see if the facility was booked by other people at a specific time
3.When user submit application, system can check if the facility was booked(Optional)

Can we leverage existing sharepoint functions for requirements above? What should we develop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are following links which you can use to achieve the goal :

http://spresourcebooking.codeplex.com/

http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/sharepoint-server-help/enable-reservation-of-resources-in-a-calendar-HA101810595.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30983/SharePoint-Reservations

https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-Double-Booking-with-the-Calendar.aspx

You can modify the above solutions based on your requirement.

I think this links are enough for you to start with.

Regards,

Comment: Appreciate to the information you provided!